# Parsing Twitter's trending #hashtags using API 1.1 without OAuth

Tags: twitter, oauth, hashtag

It looks like with the API 1.1 update I can no longer fetch trending hashtags without using OAuth. Is there a way to this without logging into Twitter?

And if Twitter doesn't provide it (without OAuth) is there another reliable service I could use? Ideally I would like to get trending topics (#hashtags) for certain locations (city or country). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the first question, you now must use OAuth for all API requests, hashtags included.
See [here](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/changes-coming-to-twitter-api).

> In version 1.1, we will require every request to the API to be authenticated

I don't know about services, but why not use OAuth? You just need "application authentication", not the user to log in.

Comment: Sure but what about the rate limit?